# about jQuery fn declaration

Tags: jquery

my two js files (`file1.js & file2.js`) works but when i made some changes in `file2.js` then it doesn't work, why?.

```
/* file1.js */
$(function() {
    $(".some").click(function() {
        ...
    });
});

/* file2.js */

window.onload = test();
function test() {
    $(".dragfile").draggable(function() {
        ...
    });
    $(".resize").resizable(function() {
       ....
    });
}
```

Now i make changes in `file2.js` and some functions are not working. `file1.js` remains same

```
/* file2.js */
// window.onload = test(); function test() {  }

$(function() { // modified              
    $(".dragfile").draggable(function() {    // this function works
        ...
    });

    $(".resize").resizable(function() {      // this isn't working
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to narrow down where the actual problem is by removing the code you changed bit by bit. Maybe we can be more of a help than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any declaration error although i'd say to go through your files again, clean server directory & publish project again.

It seems your file is not updated when you make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the jQuery documentation on [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (which you are using the `$(handler)` form of)

> The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the `<body onload="">` attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready() or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the window or to more specific items, like images.

And unless you are using a jQuery plugin that provides `.resizeable()`, like mentioned by others, you probably meant `.resize()`